# Checking Valid RSS feed URL

Tags: php, validation, rss, simplepie

I have decided to use SimplePie to parse RSS and Atom Feeds.

What I want to do is that let people to input RSS and Atom Feeds URL through text fields.

What If they put invalid RSS and Atom Feeds?

I know that invalid Feeds won't be parsed through SimplePie.

But I want to know whether the Feeds are able to be parsed through SimplePie or not.

And through that process, I want to delete those invalid RSS feed URL lists.

Checking the document type, XML or HTML will be a first step to find out the validness.

How can I do that in PHP? or is there other ways to do what I want to do?

Comment: Which version of Simplepie are you using?

Comment: @hakre I'm using ver 1.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if Simplepie is able to parse a feed or not, you can just load the feed in question and check for errors:

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://example.com/rss');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

if ($feed->error())
{
    // this feed has errors
}
```

You might want to disable the auto-discovery feature to test specific feed URLs. Additionally you can aquire the feeds data on your own and use `set_raw_data` instead of `set_feed_url`.

Answer (score 0):

Here seems to be ready-to-use function:
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?555763-Validating-an-RSS-Feed-with-PHP&p=3865285&viewfull=1#post3865285

So you just call

```
$rssvalid = validateFeed("http://yourUrlHere.com");
if($rssvalid == true){
print"Yes, it´s valid!";
} else {
print"Sorry, it´s not valid!";
}
```

Comment: I have tried this.. The problem is that this validateFeed function strictly examine the validness of Feed. Some feeds are parsable through simplepie even though the validateFeed says it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done.

```
if(strpos(file_get_contents($feed_url),'<?xml')===false) {
    //remove this $feed_url from the Feed List
    return;
}
```

This resolved basic problem What I had.